# Remove zeros from the beginning of string

Tags: excel

I have  aproblem with removing zeros from the beginning of the test string in Excel.

I do have this:

```
017 Elepha
001 Eleph.
017 Elepha
001 Eleph.
001 Eleph.
001 Eleph.
001 Eleph.
```

I need to remove all zeros from the beginning while the lenght of the string can be diverse.

Can you please help me to develop a universal formula? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Replace() function. Start are the beginning of the contents.
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php

Answer (score 0):

For the sample data:

```
=--LEFT(A1,3)&MID(A1,4,LEN(A1))
```

Takes first three characters and casts to number (where Excel automatically strips leading zeros) then concatenates with the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it in VBA like:

IF(ISERR(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""0"","" ""),3)))),"""",VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""0"","" ""),3))))"